# Executing AsyncTask from onClick of AlertDialog doesn't call opPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I am getting weird behavior when executing AsyncTask from AlertDialog. I need some suggestion/workaround to fix it. I am stuck at this point.

When I execute AsyncTask from AlertDialog, it is not calling onPostExecute. It call doInBackground, but after finish, it doesn't call onPostExecute. I want AsyncTask to get executed on the basis of AlertDialog's button press value.

Here is the function that creates AlertDialog and executes AsyncTask:

```
private void processDownloadChoosen(String msg, int __position){
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(ShivaniMP3Activity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog));
    final int position = __position;
    alertBox.setMessage(msg);
    alertBox.setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Download", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id){
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        String downloadURL = entries.get(position);
                        AsyncTaskDownload atd = new AsyncTaskDownload(downloadURL);
                        if((downloadURL != null) &&(downloadURL != "")){
                            EnglishMP3Activity.totalDownloads++;
                            if(downloadWindow == null){
                                downloadWindow = new PopupWindow(downloadPopupLayout, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
                                downloadWindow.showAtLocation(downloadPopupLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                            }
                            atd.execute();
                        }
                    }
            }).setNegativeButton("Listen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    String downloadURL = entries.get(position).replace("%20", " ");
                    emp = new EasyMediaPlayer(mp3PopupLayout,buttonPlayPause,seekBarProgress,tv_mp3,downloadURL);
                    emp.startPlayingMP3();          
                }
        }).show();
}
```

And I am calling this function from listview's on item click:

```
//lv is listview 
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p, View v, int position, long id) {
            processDownloadChoosen("Do you want to Listen or Download this file ?",position);
        }
    });
```

My AsyncTask definition look like:

```
public class AsyncTaskDownload extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
    //
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        pBar1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... vd){
        try{
            //do something
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //do somting
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... msg) {
        //do smething
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void in){
        cancelDownloadButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //do smtthing
    }
}
```

PLEASE NOTE: When I execute AsyncTask directly from ListView's on item click function, all works well. But while calling from AlertDialog, it doesn't call onPostExecute.

Any help to resolve/workaround for this is appreciated.. Advance Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using a handler/Runnable such that in the alertDialog's onPositiveClick callback you do

```
Handler mHandler;
prtected void onCreate(Bundle sis) {
    //other code
    this.mHandler = new Handler();
}

//In your DialogInterface.OnClickListener

mHandler.post(new Runnable() { 
    @Override 
    public void run() {
        //Init and launch your asynctask here
    }
});
```

The reason this is not working is that an AsyncTask must be invoked on the UI thread and im pretty sure that invoking on the positive button callback is not linked directly with the activities context (given that the task works from the ListView's onItemClick callback)

Comment: NO Brother. 
Still its not calling:

mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
String downloadURL = entries.get(position);
AsyncTaskDownload atd = new AsyncTaskDownload(downloadURL);
if((downloadURL != null) &&(downloadURL != "")){
EnglishMP3Activity.totalDownloads++;
if(downloadWindow == null){
downloadWindow = new PopupWindow(downloadPopupLayout, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
downloadWindow.showAtLocation(downloadPopupLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
}
atd.execute();
}
}

Answer (score 0):

After going through several posts, it looks like AsyncTask doesn't work properly from AlertDialog.
So I achieved this by "fooling" Android. Noe I am doing everything inside doInBackground function and also getting the feel as if preexecute/postexecute is getting called.
Below is what i did:

1) Removed onPreExecute() and onProgressUpdate() from AsyncTask.
2) define doInBackground something like:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... vd){
publishProgress("I_AM_STARTED");
//Other Work
publishProgress("I_AM_DONE");
}
```

3) define onProgressUpdate something like:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... msg) {
if(msg[0].equals("I_AM_STARTED")){
//code for onPreExecute
}
else if(msg[0].equals("I_AM_DONE")){
//code for onPostExecute
}
else{
//normal code
}
}
```

Hope this may be helpful for someone who got stuck like me. :-)